# How much smaller/bigger is ampere/second than miliampere/hour?

Tags: current-measurement

How much smaller/bigger is ampere/second than  miliampere/hour?

I want to check with people who know this way better than me at this.

Comment: Well, a millamp is one thousandth of an amp, while a second a one 3600th of an hour. So what does the math tell you? An amp.second (amp/second doesn't make much sense as a unit) is of a similar magnitude to a milliamp.hour (miliampere/hour also doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

a milliampere/hour is 0.001 amperes/hour. Since an hour contains 3600 seconds, 0.001 amperes/hour is 0.000000278 amperes/second.

Comment: See Sandro's answer instead of this one

Comment: @Phil I answered the question that was asked. The rest of you decided you knew better and didn't bother to answer the actual question.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are interested in Amperes/second and milliamperes/hour?
Those units exist (to specify how fast current is changing, for example when talking about progressively turning on some device).

However, I can't see any "basic" situation where someone not comfortable with units would need to work with them.

Instead, I suppose you are interested in A.s (amperes × seconds) and mA.h (milliamperes × hour), which are used to describe the capacity of batteries (something everyone is confronted with, not just engineers).

If so, then 1 A.s = 1A × 1s = 1000 mA × 1s = 1000 mA × (1/3600) h = 1000/3600 mA.h = 1/3.6 mA.h = 0.27777 mA.h

So if you have the capacity in A.s, you divide by 3.6 to get it in mA.h.

If you have the capacity in mA.h, then you multiply by 3.6 o get it in A.s.

So 1 A.s is less than 1 mA.h

Comment: +1. Tip: SE sites support HTML entities such as `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments). The &times; gives the '×' symbol which is much classier than an 'x' or a '*'.

Comment: didn't know about the &times;, will use it in future, especially as the '*' is overloaded with other formattting

Comment: If 1 A.s = 0.2777 mA.h then 1 A.s _is less than_ 1 mA.h

Comment: good catch @MathKeepsMeBusy : I corrected it

Answer (score 1):

> How much smaller/bigger is Ampere/second than miliampere/hour

"Ampere/sec" means ampere *per* second, and is likely not the unit you are thinking about. It would refer to the rate at which current is changing, and would be a useful unit when considering inductors. The same thing applies to milliamps/hour.

It is likely you mean amp-seconds and milliamp-hours, which are units that would apply to battery capacity.

Since there are 3600 seconds in an hour, there are 3600 milliamp-seconds in a milliamp-hours. Since there are 1000 milliamps in an amp, there are 3.6 amp-seconds in 1 milliamp-hour. So, an amp-seconds is smaller than a milliamp-hour.

If by chance you really intended amps/second, 1 amp/second is equal to 1000 milliamp/(hour/3600) = 3600000 milliamp/hour.